# Array of textfields in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, text

Is it possible to use an array of textfields, buttons and other elements in `C#`?

I have, say 25 text fields, and instead of naming them txt1, txt2, and so on, I would like to use something of the form, txt[i=1,25].

I remember using something like subscripts in `VB 6.0.`

If not possible, is there any other way to do the same?

Comment: Why not? It's possible. You can use arrays, lists and all the collections u want to.

Comment: Why don't you use any control, that is intended to display collections (e.g., ListBox, ListView)?

Comment: Wouldn't `txt[0]` be equally as arbitrary as `txt0`?  Why can't these objects have meaningful names?  What do they actually represent?

Comment: @Dennis: Am a novice with respect to this language. Some of them have suggested me that. I'll do the required. Thanks

Comment: @David: That was just an example, and not the identifiers I would be using.

Comment: @user1728695: I'm not sure, that you have any domain object, which have 25 meaningful string properties (if so, it's just a bad design). So, this 25 text fields is a collection, and there are several controls for collection-like data. Choose appropriate one, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  List<TextBox> list = new List<TextBox>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
  list.Add(new TextBox(){ID ="txtBox" +i};
  Form.Controls.Add(list[i]); // add this line if you want to actually display the textboxes on your page.
  }
```

The above snippet will add 10 textboxes to your collection, each with their own ID.

You can do the same thing with arrays ofcourse, but Lists are more flexible in my opinion.
Instead of making a List of Textboxes, you could also just make a list of Controls.
Something like:

`List<Control> x = new List<Control>();`

Comment: The answer is precise and useless at the same time. :) What he will do with the list of texboxes?

Comment: @Dennis You should ask him, if you want to know ;)

Comment: @Thousand: I'm afraid of his answer. :D +1 anyway.

Comment: @Dennis i updated my answer, i'm guessing that was where you were driving at :)

Comment: How will I add that to my 'Project'. System.Forms / Phone.Forms cannot be included. Tried all possible auto suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Here You Go,

```
 List<TextBox> list = new List<TextBox>();
 for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
 {
     list.Add(new TextBox(){ID ="txtBox" +i};
 }
```

**Note :** You can use any thing in place of `TextBox`

Comment: Accept the answer if you have got yours..;)

Comment: How will I name them when I place the same from Toolbox?

Comment: one thing you have to do is add it into the parent layout which will be form in your case

Comment: What will my line be then? I tried: LayoutRoot.____, but neither Controls nor Add show up.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
TextBox[] textboxes = new TextBox[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
   textboxes[i] = new TextBox();
   textboxes[i].Name = string.Format("txtBox{0}", i);
}
```

Comment: How will I name them when I place the same from Toolbox?

Comment: This code will throw a `NullReferenceException` during the first loop iteration as `textboxes[i]` is always `null`.

Comment: Yeah, sry my bad;) forgot about initializing a new object!

Comment: @user1728695 If u want to name them in that way, you need to place them in the code. Unless u want to place `TextBox`es with the default names from a toolbox, and then you can find them using `LINQ` or something like that and rename.